# UDP Sockets in C - Passing Integer Values

Tags: c, sockets

So I'm trying to set up a UDP connection that will take a user inputted character string, convert it to hexadecimal, and send it to the server. I've been told it's possible to send things other than a character array through sockets (which is the only way I've done it before), but I've hit a few walls. First off, I was getting a whole load of errors when I explicitly sent an integer (complaining about casting integer to pointer), so I cast it as a void pointer instead. I don't get the warning messages, but I get the same error.

My question is: Have I made a mistake in the logic setting up the socket, or is it not possible to do what I'm trying to do?

```
void main(){

  /*Create UDP socket*/
  clientSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);                    //setup the socket with an address structure and frame type

  /*Configure settings in address struct*/
  serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                                  //set the type of address
  serverAddr.sin_port = htons(7891);                                //set the port number you'll be using
  serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");              //set the address you're sending to
  memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);    //Just something that needs to be done

  /*Initialize size variable to be used later on*/
  addr_size = sizeof serverAddr;
  pthread_t thread;
  int t = 0;
  int message;

  while(1){
    memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof buffer);
    printf("Type a sentence to send to server:\n");
    fgets(buffer,1024,stdin);
    printf("You typed: %s",buffer);
    message = ChartoInt(buffer);
    printf("You are sending: %x\n", message);
    /*Send message to server*/
    t = sendto(clientSocket,(void*)message,sizeof(message),0,(struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr,addr_size);
    printf("The Value of t is %x\n",t);
  }
}
```

Comment: You really don't need to "convert to hexadecimal". The data is already represented in numerical way inside the computer and the data link. Just pass the string as is.

Comment: Before you try to send anything over UDP, define precisely how the information you're going to send should be encoded as a chunk of bytes.

Comment: I know it converts it already, but I need to add in Bit stuffing later, and I thought this would be the easiest way to do it, if it was already in a numerical form. The program is by no means finished yet David, I will have that implemented later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* send a single integer over a socket. It will travel as 4 or 8 bytes, and the byte order can be different on different CPU types, so that can be a problem.

But what you are doing is trying to use an integer as a pointer. What you really want is something like

```
t = sendto(clientSocket,&message,sizeof(message),0,(struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr,addr_size);
```

Note the address-of operator "`&`" on `message`.

Comment: I think what he really wants is `sendto(clientSocket,buffer,strlen(buffer)...`

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Nope, because he went to the bother of converting buffer into an integer with ChartoInt.

Comment: Why is it that you don't need that operator if you send an array of characters? Is that already defined as a pointer then?

Comment: @Michael: Exactly. An array in C decays into a pointer to the first array element.